# Trivial RowVersion Question

Tags: sql-server

Is there a method or syntax that would allow a table that just has a rowversion/timestamp column to be filled with data?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TimeStamp_Test]([row_version] [timestamp] NOT NULL)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure why you would need this but yes it is possible.

```
Insert into [dbo].[TimeStamp_Test] default values;
```

Or

```
Insert into [dbo].[TimeStamp_Test] values (default);
```

To do multiple rows you can use [`merge`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12863422/insert-multiple-rows-of-default-values-into-a-table/12863711#12863711).

Comment: Thank you. I had tried inserting default, but not "default values".

Comment: @john `Insert into [dbo].[TimeStamp_Test] values (default)` should also work. Online demo of both http://rextester.com/QQGX73516

Comment: I just have to say, yikes. I don't know what I did wrong. I've lost the original insert query, but yes, that too works just fine. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: "I'm not sure why you would need this but yes it is possible." - Just fooling around with the data type, and created a simple setup to look at a working timestamp, but then had trouble filling it... Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You can also poppulate default values from a resultset, which is quicker for generating a lot of values.  For `rowversion` (aka `timestamp`) you can select a `null` into it.  I often use this technique for springing up test rigs quickly.

```
USE tempdb
GO

SET NOCOUNT ON

-- Create a large table
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.largeTable') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE dbo.largeTable
CREATE TABLE dbo.largeTable ( rowId INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, someData UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT NEWID(), dateAdded DATETIME DEFAULT GETDATE(), addedBy VARCHAR(30) DEFAULT SUSER_NAME(), ts ROWVERSION )
GO

-- Populate table: this took just under a min on my laptop
BEGIN TRAN
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.largeTable DEFAULT VALUES
GO 1000000
COMMIT TRAN


-- This took < 2 seconds
;WITH cte AS (
SELECT TOP 1000000 ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY ( SELECT 1 ) ) rn
FROM master.sys.columns c1
    CROSS JOIN master.sys.columns c2
    CROSS JOIN master.sys.columns c3
)
INSERT INTO dbo.largeTable ( ts )
SELECT NULL
FROM cte
```

Comment: BTW: I just happened to notice that [Ability to insert null values into timestamp columns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143729.aspx) is deprecated

Comment: Good spot @MartinSmith.  Using it fires a deprecation announcement: "The ability to INSERT NULL values into TIMESTAMP columns will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use it. Use DEFAULT instead."